# Hyperlink to specific page or folder with default document?

Tags: html, asp.net, web, responsive-design

We are in the process of redesigning our company's web site, and we have been told by consultants that it is important that we either:

1.) Always link to a specific page i.e. foo.com/buy/default.aspx

- or -

2.) Always link to a directory and allow the default document to load i.e. foo.com/buy/ where "default.aspx" is the default document

Is there any practical benefit to either approach? Does being 100% consistent in doing one or the other really gain us anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, always linking to a specific page helps prevent ambiguity in your URLs. Prefer a canonical URL (can be with or without a file extension). If you have to have multiple URLs for a single resource, for example **/products/product1.aspx** and **products?productID=product1**, then take advantage of the Canonical URL property in your code to specify which is the *proper* one.

Using extensionless URLs allows you to change technologies later. For example, **/blog/post1.aspx** is different than **/blog/post1.php**, say if you ever switched to WordPress (not common, of course, but it happens). It's just an easy way to make the links work no matter the technology. Plus, in my opinion it's always better to, as much as possible, mask the technology stack that you're using where possible. Extensionless URLs are becoming the norm (in my opinion) as people seem to be moving more toward an API-based approach to URIs as resources, and mixed technology stacks.

Answer (score 1):

The second method you mentioned is good because it helps you make clean URLs

(don't click these urls they are just examples)

okay URL
http://www.example.com/example/example.php

clean URL
http://www.example.com/example/ (**so much easier to remember, and shorter to write out**)

here is a good tutorial I found that shows you how to accomplish this: http://www.desiquintans.com/cleanurls (htaccess)